# Find table cell knowing row and column ids with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a simple table, where I have set IDs for headers and IDs for rows. Given an ID for both, I need to find a corresponding cell at the intersection of those two.

Example:

```
<table id="tablica">
    <thead>
        <th id="bla">Bla</th>
        <th id="bli">Bli</th>
        <th id="blu">Blu</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="jedan">
            <td>1</td>            
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="dva">
            <td>4</td>            
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tri">
            <td>7</td>            
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​​​
```

So if I have id="bli" and id="dva", that means I want to do something with cell having value 5 in this example.

**edit:** There are a lot of correct answers, I upvoted all of them, but unfortunately I can only choose one as correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
var column = $('#bli').index();
var cell = $('#dva').find('td').eq(column);
```

And working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8nWf/2/

added all in a function:

```
function getCell(column, row) {
    var column = $('#' + column).index();
    var row = $('#' + row)
    return row.find('td').eq(column);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/t8nWf/5/

Comment: change `$('#tablica').find('thead').find('#bli').index();` to `$('#bli').index()`. much faster!

Answer (score 3):

If you have got the id of the row you can select the column having data 5 into it.

```
$("#dva").find("td:contains(5)").css({"background-color":"red"});
```

Also refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sEGf/3/) as working example.

**EDIT**
Without knowing the id of the row you only have id to table, then you can also find the cell :

```
$("#tablica tr").find("td:contains(5)").css({"background-color":"red", "padding":"5px"});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3sEGf/7/)

Comment: I think he doesn't know the value of the TD (my assumption).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#dva > td').eq($('#bli').index()); // returns the td element
```

should work. Working example:
http://jsbin.com/acevon/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: This returns all TDs in target TR.

Comment: I guess you fixed it. The original version did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/sMH5K/

Comment: This was a typo, you must have been very fast ;).

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the TD element you want as a jQuery object:

```
var thIndex = $( '#tablica #bli' ).index (); // get index of TH in thead
var $td = $( $( '#dva td' ).get ( thIndex ) ); // get the TD in the target TR on the same index as is in the thead
```

[JSFiddle example](http://var%20thIndex%20=%20%24%28%20%27#tablica%20#bli%27%20%29.index%20%28%29;%20//%20get%20index%20of%20TH%20in%20thead%20var%20%24td%20=%20%24%28%20%24%28%20%27#dva%20td%27%20%29.get%20%28%20thIndex%20%29%20%29;%20//%20%20alert%20%28%20%24td.html%20%28%29%20%29;%E2%80%8B)

Comment: `#tablica th#bli` is a pretty bad selector. Because an id is unique, you could just query `#bli`.