# Selecting a particular jQuery datatable column value programatically

Tags: select, row, datatables

Can some one please tell me how to get a particular column of particular row in a jQuery data table?

E.g.

```
var column_value = tablename.row(x).column(y);
```

There are lot of examples for selecting a row data in an `onclick` event. But what I'm requesting here is a method to select a row and column programatically, without user clicking on a particular row.

Comment: Assuming you've assigned id's to your rows/columns, you can use something like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277934/find-table-cell-knowing-row-and-column-ids-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277934/find-table-cell-knowing-row-and-column-ids-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm afraid this table is being generated dynamically I've not assigned any id's neither to columns no rows. I'll look in to this option as well.

Comment: You can assign properties using Databales API methods, e.g `fnRowCallback` can be used to add an id to a row or cells

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been able to solve my issue based on your input. I've used "createdRow: function ( row, data, index )" as mentioned in http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

Comment: Hi, i am also facing similar issue, could any one help me please. I have DataTable values which are dynamicall created(23 fields are there -23 columns),  I have to find the emailid's in each row and append the checkbox to the perticular column header.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the examples is focusing on the most common use, like working on a particular row on click, which also demonstrates how to use the [**`cell-selector`**](http://datatables.net/reference/type/cell-selector). Basically you can pass a string, an object, a node etc, like

```js
table.cell('tbody tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2)');
table.cell(this);
table.cell($('#column'));
```

But it is very poor documented that you actually also can use

```js
var column_value = table.cell(6,1).data();
```

which seems to be what you are looking for. Be aware that `cell(row,col)` return values from the underlying HTML table, unlike `cell(selector)` that return values from the dynamic table, eg sorting and filtering. `Cells(row,col)` is really handy when you know the precise index of a column in the original table. You can console out the entire content of a table like this :

```js
for (var y=0;y<rowCount;y++) {
   for (var x=0;x<colCount;x++) {
      console.log(table.cell(y,x).data());
   }
}
```

You can change the content of a column like this :

```js
table.cell(y,x).data('new content')
```

Also remember that `cell` is zero-based, unlike the jQuery selector. The counterpart to `table.cell(6,1).data()` is

```js
var value = table.cell('tbody tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2)').data();
```

equal to

```js
var value = $('#example tbody tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2)').html();
```

both returning dynamic data, `table.cell(6,1).data()` will return the unsorted, unfiltered value.

The above examples can be seen here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/z95Br/**

Comment: So @Asa, did the answer helped you out or should I delete it?